# Rails 3.2 not recognizing route with optional parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, rails-routing

I haven't used optional parameters in routes often, and this problem has got me stumped:  I have the following route defined as the first route in routes.rb:

**get '/employees/hours_summary(/:year/:month/:day(:/prev_or_next))' => 'employees#hours_summary', as: :employees_hours_summary**

rake routes indicates that it's OK:

employees_hours_summary GET    /employees/hours_summary(/:year/:month/:day(:/prev_or_next))(.:format) employees#hours_summary

But this route fails:
**localhost:3500/employees/hours_summary/2014/02/02/next**

Routing Error: No route matches [GET] "/employees/hours_summary/2014/02/02/next"

while this one works fine (omitting the "/next" on the end):
**localhost:3500/employees/hours_summary/2014/02/02**

Am I missing something really obvious here?  This route seems to match the examples given in the Rails guide on routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in the route. It should be /:prev_or_next not :/prev_or_next

`get '/employees/hours_summary(/:year/:month/:day(/:prev_or_next))' => 'employees#hours_summary', as: :employees_hours_summary`

Comment: arrrrrgh!!!!!!   Thank you!  I stared at that for 30 minutes, sensing it would be something stupid like that!